# Laravel 5.4 - Use column-sortable

Tags: php, laravel, eloquent

I'm trying to use column-sortable for my laravel 5.4 (https://github.com/Kyslik/column-sortable),

My model :

```
    class InfoBird extends Model
{
    public $timestamps = false;
    protected $primaryKey = "id_oiseau";
    protected $table = "oiseau";

    use Sortable;

    public $sortable = [ 
        'nom_codifie',
        'nom_commun',
        'etat_actuel',
        'pays',
        'date_reception',
        'date_renvoi',
        'immatriculation',
        'nom_local'
    ];

    public function getBirds() {
        $birds = DB::table('oiseau as oi')
            ->leftJoin('local_lpo', 'oi.id_local_lpo', 'local_lpo.id_local_lpo');

        return $birds;
    }
 }
```

My controller :

```
public function birds() {

        $infoBirds = new InfoBird;
        $birds = $infoBirds->getBirds();

        $birds = $birds->sortable()->paginate(15);

        //$birds = InfoBird::sortable()->paginate(15);

        return view('pages.birds', compact('birds'));
    }
```

It was working before i add the model ( there was only the sentence in comment ). 
But now i have this eror :

`Call to undefined method Illuminate\Database\Query\Builder::sortable()`

I'am running out of idea to fix that, i appreciate your help !

Comment: Why are you trying to accomplish calling to "sortable"? And where is that method defined?

Comment: It's define in the Model InfoBird

Comment: show it in the code. We can only see an array called "sortable"

Comment: I just edited with the full model

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`getbirds()` returns a `QueryBuilder`, so you are trying to access to the `sortable` method of a `QueryBuilder` (which does not exist), instead of the `sortable` method of the model Infobird (which does exist).

Try this:

```
    $info = Infobird::sortable()->leftjoin('local_lpo', 'oi.id_local_lpo', 'local_lpo.id_local_lpo')->paginate(15);
    return view('pages.birds', compact('birds'));
```

Comment: Ok but how can I call the `sortable` method of InfoBird ?

Comment: but why do you need to call any "`sortable`" method?

Comment: I don't really understand how it is working but as it say in the documentation i need to call it : https://github.com/Kyslik/column-sortable . I tried without calling `sortable` but it's not working.